# UserScript: run JavaScript on password fields as they're loaded

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, userscripts

I want to write a user script that runs some custom JavaScript code on each `<input type="password">` field that gets loaded. I could register an event handler on document load to look for all input fields and run the JavaScript code on them, but that means firstly that the JavaScript code won't run on input fields that subsequently get added by other JavaScript code, and secondly it won't run until the page is fully loaded.

I want to put [ChromaHash](http://mattt.github.com/Chroma-Hash) into all of my password fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) library could do this for you. It would look like this:

```
$('input').livequery(function() {
  doSomethingToTheInput(this); //this == the input
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks like exactly what I want.

Totally impressed with StackOverflow, this being my first question here and it having been answered in under 15 minutes.

Answer (score -2):

The **featuers of the livequery plugin where integrated into the latest jQuery** you can now use them by calling [`live()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live).

Example:

Comment: I don't think jQuery's .live() function supports the "load" event... at least, it doesn't seem to be listed on http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live